# For each number find ads that was published with only that number

Tags: mysql, sql, not-exists

My database app contains tree tables `phone`, `ad` and `phone_ad`.
each ad could be published with one phone or more in `phone_ad` table.

phone:

```
---------------------
ph_id | number
---------------------
0     | xxx-xxx-xxxx
1     | yyy-yyy-yyyy
2     | zzz-zzz-zzzz
---------------------
```

ad:

```
-----------------------
ad_id   | ad_text
-----------------------
11      | text_1
12      | text_2
13      | text_3
-----------------------
```

phone_ad:

```
------------------
ad_id  | ph_id
------------------
11      | 0
12      | 0
12      | 2
13      | 0
14      | 1
14      | 2
------------------
```

I am trying to find for each number (let's say the number with ph_id = 0) the ads that was published with only that number. it means in this case ads that have ad_id = 11 and ad_id = 13. I have tried the query bellow but it seems that it wouldn't work

```
SELECT ad_id 
FROM phone_ad 
WHERE ph_id = 0 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ad_id FROM phone_ad WHERE ph_id <> 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to *correlate* the subquery with the outer query so they relate to the same `ad_id`:

```
SELECT ad_id 
FROM phone_ad p
WHERE 
    ph_id = 0 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT ad_id 
        FROM phone_ad p1 
        WHERE 
            p1.ad_id = p.ad_id     -- correlation on ad_id
            AND p1.ph_id <> p.ph_id
    )
```

Comment: you mean  `p1.ad_id = p.ad_id `. it worked. thank you

Comment: Welcome @adeladl, and thanks for spotting the typo, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join on sabquery for the result of the group by ad_id  with countdistinct ph_id  = 1

```
select p.ad_id 
from phone_ad p
INNER JOIN  (
  SELECT ad_id 
  FROM phone_ad 
  GROUP BY  ad_id
  having count(distinct ph_id) =1 
) t on t.ad_id  = p.ad_id 
WHERE ph_id = 0
```